# Update yum package using localinstall

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rhel

If a package is installed using **yum localinstall** like this:

```
yum -y localinstall --nogpgcheck some-package-1.0.0.rpm
```

And now, if I try to run:

```
yum -y localinstall --nogpgcheck some-package-2.0.0.rpm
```

Will it replace the entire old version with the new one or does it maintain both the versions?

Comment: ' "yum localinstall" is deprecated because "yum install" now does exactly the same thing when given a path to an RPM file rather than just a package name. ' source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/yum-localinstall-question-4175598142/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer is, it depends on how `some-package` is packaged. In general, most of the `.rpms` packaged with `foo-version-release.rpm` gets obsoleted by the same package `foo` with `version++` and/or `release++`.

Looking at your `some-package`, if you would run `yum localinstall some-package-2.0.0.rpm` (note, not with `-y`), then you would see message from `yum`, something like this:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package foo.x86_64 0:1.0.0 will be updated
---> Package foo.x86_64 0:2.0.0 will be an update
```

This tells that `yum` is going to update the package and remove the old one. `yum` resolves these dependencies whereas a `rpm -ivh` won't do it.

Now, there are special cases, e.g., `kernel` where it will be installed on the system side-by-side with the old one, unless you manual invoked a `rpm -Uvh kernel*.rpm` command.

Equivalent command to the `yum localinstall` would be two-fold,

```
# This will fail if some-2.0.0 is designed to obsolete some-1.0.0
$ rpm -ivh --test some-2.0.0.rpm
```

whereas following would succeed:

```
$ rpm -Uvh --test some-2.0.0.rpm
```

Note, I am using `--test` to do a dry-run. One needs to remove it for a real installation.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer.  The first part is an extremely good reason to avoid -y.  Reviewing what YUM says it is going to do is a good way to prevent accidental misconfigurations.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using the same pkg manager for everything now that there repo-based package managers.

It doesn't appear to be documented but indeed works w/ the standard yum args:

`yum -y localupdate some-package-2.0.0.rpm`