# How to install software on a prorietary linux distro with no repos given?

Tags: linux, yum, rhel, dnf

I want to install some basic packages on a proprietary Linux distro based on RHEL (I think).

I tried going the usual `dnf install foo` way, but quickly found out there are no repositories in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.

Since it is based on RHEL, I tried adding some RHEL repos, but still cannot install anything from them. I also tried downloading a package and install it from a local repo as explained [here](https://www.clevernetsystems.com/installing-rhel-packages-without-network-connection/). But no packages are detected in the repo. My guess is that the proprietary distro is (too?) different from RHEL so those repos are not recognized.

So my question is: How do I install packages on a proprietary Linux distro? Is it only possible to install from repos that are meant precisely for the distro I am using? Or could it be that repos for another distro might work? The only other way I can think of is to try to find all the Git repos of all the packages I want to install to install them from source.

Comment: If it uses `rpm`, you can download the `yourfile-version.x.y.rpm` file and install with `rpm -Uvh yourfile-version.x.y.rpm`. (that's what `yum` does after downloading the file. You will need root privileges.

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you are absolutely right, sorry! Thanks anyways for the suggestion with rpm, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few possible ways:

1. activate your RHEL machine.. This include create account in RH. And
   its free for small number of machines. More info [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/02/10/how-to-activate-your-no-cost-red-hat-enterprise-linux-subscription).
2. Download the package and do a local install:

   `dnf localinstall package.rpm`

You should download and install all dependent packages also.

To update you can use nondocumented option:

```
dnf localupdate package.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I have to check back with my company's IT department about registration of the machine, but I got an rpm from rpmfind.net and was able to install it using your step #2. Only problem with this is that updating packages will be a very tedious task.

Comment: You can check this answer about update a package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48694191/2908599

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I will write a script to take care of updating the manually installed packages. Then I only need to download the newer .rpm-files manually.

Comment: @olpohl, about update I will add a option (nondocumented)